# Batch - If variable value is around a number

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement

How do I detect numbers near to a value? I have the following code, but I would like to shorten it.

```bat
SET /A "AI_1=%AI%-2"
SET /A "AI_2=%AI%-1"

SET /A "AI_1h=%AI%+1"
SET /A "AI_2h=%AI%+2"

IF %Speed% EQU %AI_2% GOTO :ACCELERATE
IF %Speed% EQU %AI_1% GOTO :ACCELERATE

IF %Speed% EQU %AI% GOTO :ACCELERATE

IF %Speed% EQU %AI_1H% GOTO :ACCELERATE
IF %Speed% EQU %AI_2H% GOTO :ACCELERATE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a little cryptic, but this shortens the code

```dos
2>nul set /a "1/((speed-ai-1)*(speed-ai)*(speed-ai+1))" || goto :ACCELERATE
```

It just tries to calculate a division. If the `speed` value is in the range `[AI-1 .. AI+1]` at least one of the elements in the divisor will be `0`, so the multiplication will be `0`and the division will fail with an *division by zero error*. The conditional operator `||` (run next command if the previous one failed) will handle this case.

If the values of `speed` and `ai` are high (batch arithmetic only handle integer signed 32bit values), then the operation should be separated into three different divisions to avoid an overflow in the multiplication

```dos
2>nul set /a "1/(speed-ai-1), 1/(speed-ai), 1/(speed-ai+1)" || goto :ACCELERATE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EQU : Equal
NEQ : Not equal
LSS : Less than <
LEQ : Less than or Equal <=
GTR : Greater than >
GEQ : Greater than or equal >=
```

I would combine LEQ and GEQ to defermine if you have a number close to your current one.

source: https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: Nice idea! However as I said the code is supposed to compare 2 variables. The variable value may change so I think LEQ and GEQ is not very helpful in this case.....

Comment: You could just keep checking when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

This `for` loop loops through `AI-3` to `AI+3`, and do an `if` comparison on each integer between them.

```
SET /A "AI_3Lower=%AI%-3"
SET /A "AI_3Higher=%AI%+3"

for /l %%G in (%AI_3Lower,1,%AI_3Higher) do (
    if %Speed% EQU %%G goto :accelerate
)
```

Comment: Was around looking for a solution and something like this was what i was gonna try next for you but seems you got it. nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea you've already dismissed:

```bat
Set/A "Upper=AI+2,Lower=AI-2"
If %Speed% GEq %Lower% If %Speed% LEq %Upper% GoTo ACCELERATE
```

Comment: Great idea. But the %AI% variable will need to be increased by 2.

Comment: I created code which does what your code did shorter. I can only provide responses according to the information in front of me. I have edited my post according to your latest comment.